# How to convert snort log to json file

Tags: json, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, snort

i am still beginner and i have a project
i am building an Intrusion Detection system web application based on snort IDS open source version 2.9 and i am trying to display the output of snort in the dashboard but i couldn't convert the file log to json file so it could be displayed in the web  . I am using flask for the backend and mysql for the databse .

i tried to parse the the log file into json file but i can't run it with Flask and i can't store the output in SQL database.

Comment: please provide log example. also is it a MSSQL or MySQL?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.